# LibGDX: Can't add a Texture in my Table

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have a problem with my texture. The table works perfect, but when I try to add a texture Android Studio doesn't agree with me.

```
private Sprite tiger2;
```

.

```
 batch.begin();
    batch.setColor(tiger2.getColor());
    batch.draw(
            tiger2,
            Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2f - tiger2.getRegionWidth() / 2f,
            Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2f - tiger2.getRegionHeight() / 2f,
            tiger2.getRegionWidth(),
            tiger2.getRegionHeight()

    );
    batch.end();
```

.

```
 tiger2 = new Sprite(new Texture("tiger2.png"));
```

.

I don't know if this is how I should write it:

```
table.add(tiger2);
```

I get this error: 
Cannot resolve method 'add(com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite)'

```
table.add(**tiger2**);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to add a `Sprite` to the table not a `Texture` and this is the core reason why you are having problems. It is basically the same as doing `int i = "Hello World"` which would yield a error like `incompatible types`. In other words a `Integer` container cannot hold a `String`.

If you hover over the line you will see that `table.add` expects a actor. If you would go to the definition of `Sprite` you notice that this does not extend Actor in any way. So doing `Actor a = new Sprite()` results in the same error as above, you cannot put a `Sprite object` in a `Actor container`. These are core fundamentals of programming.

So what are compatible Actors? Everything that inherits Actor such as Label, TextButton, Table, ScrollPane, Window, Dialogue, etc. You can extend `Action` yourself too and create your very own Actor, but since you are struggling with this you should wait with this.

The easiest solution is to use `scene2d.ui.Image`. If you inspect this class you see it extends from `Widget` and if you inspect `Widget` you see it extends from `Actor` and thus Image is a actor since you are a child of your mother and your mother of your grandmother.

If you inspect what the `Image` constructor takes then you will notice the easiest thing to do is to create a `SpriteDrawable`, since Image does not take a `Sprite` like `table.add` does not take a Sprite either. `SpriteDrawable` takes a sprite and is a `Drawable` and that is compatible with the constructor of `Image`.

```
Image image = new Image(new SpriteDrawable(mySprite));
table.add(image);
```

Image takes a Texture too so if you are not doing fancy `Sprite` stuff with your sprite you can just create the Image with a `Texture` as well. You can see this in your IDE by typing `new Image(` and intellisense will let you know the compatible constructors.

Try to understand these types and use your IDE and the documentation to find out what you can use. With Android Studio you can right click a class and do `goto -> declaration` and see the class in question. Other IDE's have equivalent methods unless you are using something like Notepad of course.

Comment: yes, but you can create the Image with a texture, no need of sprites - new Image(texture);

Comment: @YasenBagalev I do mention that. But if you want to maintain the state of the sprite, which can be altered then you can add the `SpriteDrawable`

Comment: Sorry, didn't saw it :)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the table is a Scene2D Table:

A texture is not an actor and cannot be added to a table. To fix this you can add the texture to an Image (an actor containing a texture). It would look something like this:

```
Image tiger2Image = new Image(new Texture("tiger2.png"));
table.add(tiger2Image);
```